# How do I root the Android emulator?

Tags: rooting, android-emulator

How do I root the Android emulator?  I need root to install an .apk file on the emulator.

Comment: If you're not fond of command lines, you can also explore the emulator with the Eclipse ADT plugin. The plugin integrates a couple of development tools like ADB, DDMS, logcat, etc. I find it very interesting to connect my phone with USB (enable USB Debugging) and watch how everything works, and the same can be done for the emulator.

Answer (score 23):

The Android emulator gives you root access, you don't need to root it.  Check out [the emulator section on android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) for details on how to do things as root, [for example](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#advanced):

> `-shell`
>
> Create a *root* shell console on the current terminal. It differs from the `adb shell` command in the following ways:
>
> - It creates a root shell that allows you to modify many parts of the system.
> - It works even if the adb daemon in the emulated system is broken.
> - Pressing Ctrl+C (⌘C) stops the emulator, instead of the shell.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $ emulator @Nexus_5X_API_23 -shell
> ```

Comment: Although you get 'root' access, some folders are owned by system, and root can't see into it. You your device was truly rooted, I hope you can see into these folders.